# Warning after upgrading Android Gradle Plugin to 7.1.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-jetpack-compose

After upgrading  Android Gradle Plugin from 7.0.3 to 7.1.1, while building my project I get the following warning:

```
> Task :app:hiltAggregateDepsDebug
WARNING: [Processor] Library '/home/XXXX/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/XXXXXXX/transformed/core-1.7.0-api.jar' contains references to both AndroidX and old support library. This seems like the library is partially migrated. Jetifier will try to rewrite the library anyway.
 Example of androidX reference: 'androidx/core/R$styleable'
 Example of support library reference: 'android/support/v4/app/INotificationSideChannel$Default'
[Processor] Library '/home/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/XXXXXXX/transformed/core-1.7.0-api.jar' contains references to both AndroidX and old support library. This seems like the library is partially migrated. Jetifier will try to rewrite the library anyway.
```

Project info - Android Kotlin w/ Jetpack compose:

```
kotlin_version = '1.5.31'  
compose_version = '1.0.5'  
hilt_version = '2.40.5'
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.1'
```

I am using Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 1.

Why is this warning happening? How can I fix this?

Answer (score -2):

In all likelihood, your Compose and Kotlin versions are out of date. Try using these settings in your project's gradle.build:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.1.0-rc01'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.1'
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.0'
    }
}
```

You should also update your app's build.gradle file (and those in other modules) to have something like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "31.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "dev.wirespec.topdog"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionName "1.0.0"

    }
    
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11'
        useIR = true
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
        kotlinCompilerVersion '1.6.0'
    }
}
```

While this uses Java 11, you can still stick with Java 8 if you have to.

Finally, you should update the latest version of the Kotlin plugin which is version 211-1.6.10-release-923-AS7442.40

`Android Studio > Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > Kotlin`

Comment: @Johann  I have the same problem and tried your solution failed.

Comment: Works on my machine with those settings.